# Get 3 hierarchies in Azure Devops server query for tasks and user story

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I have task that has dependency between each other. They are linked as predecessor.

I've created a query that shows this predecessor but only for tasks.
I'd like to show the UserStory (parent) of the task. Is it possible?

I tried to edit the query through SQL but it didn`t work.

```
Today is showing just
Task A
   Task B

What I like is?
User Story 123
   Task A
     Task B
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible to totally meet your demand on the work item query in Azure DevOps.

There is a workaround that can be very close to your demand. On the query, you can select "**Work items and direct links**" as the **Type of query**. Then under "**Type of query**", select '**Parent**' and '**Predecessor**'.

With this method, the query result will return the linked parent item and predecessor items. However, the result will show as:

```
Task A
  User Story <--- Parent
  Task B <--- Predecessor
```

NOT

```
User Story <--- Parent
  Task A
    Task B <--- Predecessor
```

[image]

If you really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion).

**[UPDATE]**

Sure, you can open the query on Power BI directly from the query editor page on Azure DevOps via the [**Open in Power BI extension**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stansw.vsts-open-in-powerbi).

- Install the **Open in Power BI extension** from Marketplace to your Azure DevOps organization/collection.
- Open the work item query in your project on Azure DevOps.
- Click on the "**More actions**" menu icon.
- Then you can see the option "**Open in Power BI**" from the menu. Click it to open the current query in Power BI.

[image]

For more information, you can reference the document "[**Extensions and manage queries**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-support-integration-cross-service-extensions?view=azure-devops#extensions-and-manage-queries)".

Comment: Do you know if is it possible to create this query on PowerBI ?

Comment: Hi @MarcoAurélioAndrade, I have updated my above answer with more information about your question. Please check it.